# TypeError: jQuery.easing is not a function [jQuery.easing.def]

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

When I am executing my application, the slider is not showing images, I have referred related questions on stackoverflow still getting same error. Below is my script code:

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
 <!-- Skitter JS -->
<link href="skitter/skitter.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="skitter/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="skitter/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="skitter/jquery.skitter.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     //jQuery.noConflict();
     jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
         $('.box_skitter_large').skitter({ interval: 3000 });
         $('.skitter-large').skitter({
             mode: "cover",
             numbers: true,
             dots: false,
             theme: 'clean',
             numbers_align: 'left',
             height: '75%',
             width: '75%'


             //progressbar: true,
             //dots: true,
             //preview: true
         });

     });
 </script>
</asp:Content>
```